# Strange characters in RESTFUL request using Spring Integration

Tags: java, rest, spring-integration, restful-url

I am stuck trying to pass the `'ñ'` spanish character through a restful call to be catched by my int-http:inbound-gateway:

```
http://.../app/elements?status=asñd
```

If the 'ñ' caracter goes in the payload it works but is failing when is used within the URL as param.

The request has the correct charset header included so I think must be related to the way Spring Integration manage it.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: What are you using on the client side? Because it's part of the URL, special characters need URL escaping.

Comment: I am using DevHttpClient with testing purposes, I have not integrated the presentation layer yet. OK, I though was an server problem. Thanks.